Angular handling/detecting browser back button navigation
I have written code to handle browser navigation using the router, but I'm experiencing an issue where navigation is already happening before my custom confirmation dialog opens. Can anyone suggest a solution to stay on same page?"
Navigation service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {
  private internalNavigation = false;
  //private previousUrl: string | null = null;

  private navigationEventSource = new Subject<string>();
  navigationEvent$ = this.navigationEventSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {
    console.log("Navigation service called>>>");
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        //const currentUrl = event.url;
        if (event.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
          console.log("Navigation service called with pop state>>>");
          if (this.internalNavigation) {
            this.navigationEventSource.next('internal');
            this.internalNavigation = false;
          } else {
            this.navigationEventSource.next('browser');
            // Push dummy state to history to prevent actual back navigation
            //history.pushState(null, '');
          }
        } else {
          this.navigationEventSource.next('internal');
        }
        //this.previousUrl = currentUrl;
      }
    });
    // Push initial dummy state to history
    //history.pushState(null, '');
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.internalNavigation = true;
    this.location.back();
  }
}

app.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    // Prevent browser back button navigation
    history.pushState(null, '');
    this.navigationSubscription = this.navigationService.navigationEvent$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscriber)
    ).subscribe(event => {
      if (event === 'internal') {
        // Handle internal navigation logic here
      } else if (event === 'browser') {
        this.userSubscription = this.userProviderService.getUserDetails()
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe((userDetails: UserSessionObject | null) => {
          if (userDetails && userDetails.user) {
              this.sessionLogout("BackButtonTap"); 
            if (!this.isDialogOpen) {
              this.openBackButtonDialog();
            }
          } 
        });
      }
    });
  }

custom dialog
openBackButtonDialog = () => {
    this.isDialogOpen = true;
    this.backRef = this.dialogService.open(this.backButtonDialogTemplate, {
      context: '',
      hasBackdrop: true,
      closeOnBackdropClick: false,
      closeOnEsc: false
    });
    this.backRef.onClose.subscribe((result) => {
      //handling the confirm dialog opening immedialtely after close
      this.isDialogOpen = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isDialogOpen = false;
      }, 500);

      if(result) {
        history.pushState(null, '');
        this.sessionLogout("BackButtonTap"); //logged out the session
      } else {
        history.forward(); //stay on the same page
      }
    });
   
  }


All you need is the hostlistener event at the root of your application. This will open the popup when back button or close button.
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload() {
    return this.canDeactivate();
  }
  ...

  ...
  canDeactivate(): any {
    return window.confirm('There are unsaved changes! Are you sure?');
  }

Stopping the user from navigating can be done using a simple can deactivate guard.
When close button pressed, we can listen for the window unload event and call canDeactivate to also handle the scenario.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(
    component: CanComponentDeactivate,
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): CanDeactivateType {
      return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
  
}

can deactivate
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.scss'],
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  isSaved = false;
  userDetailsForm: FormGroup;

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload() {
    return this.canDeactivate();
  }

  constructor() {
    this.userDetailsForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  canDeactivate(): any {
    return window.confirm('There are unsaved changes! Are you sure?');
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSaved = true;
  }
}

Forked Stackblitz

Thanks Murali. But my requirement is to restrict the user to click on back button and once click, need to open a custom dialog to exit or stay on same page. This is for all the components. i have achieved this but before opening the dialog the page is going back to previous screen.

@vishnu updated my answer
